# UIBarButtonItem Title Text is Always Global Tint Color

Tags: ios, uitableview, uinavigationcontroller, uibarbuttonitem, uinavigationitem

iOS 7.0 and up.

In AppDelegate.m, I'm setting my global tintColor: `self.window.tintColor = myGlobalTintColor;`.

In my table view controller where I want a red trash can button in the navigation bar while editing the table view cells, I have this:

```
- (void)setEditing:(BOOL)editing animated:(BOOL)animate {
    [super setEditing:editing animated:animate];
    if (editing) { // Start editing
        self.deleteBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemTrash target:self action:@selector(deleteButtonPressed)];
        [self.deleteBarButtonItem setTitleTextAttributes:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys: [UIColor redColor],  NSForegroundColorAttributeName, nil] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItems = @[self.deleteBarButtonItem];
    }
}
```

Despite the line of code that is setting `NSForegroundColorAttributeName` to `[UIColor redColor],` I never see the red color.  When the button it set to `.enabled = YES`, I simply see it in my global tint color, like all the other buttons:
[image: UINavigationBar with always tinted UIBarButtonItem]

I've combed through my code and I'm sure there are no other locations where I'm setting anything else to `myGlobalTintColor`.  It's worth noting that this `UITableViewController` is instantiated from a storyboard.  Commenting out the line in AppDelegate.m just sends everything back to the default blue `tintColor`, but I still don't get the red color on the delete button.

Comment: Have you tried setting the tint color rather than the title text attributes?

Comment: Did you try `[self.deleteBarButtonItem setTintColor:[UIColor redColor]];` instead of `setTitleTextAttributes:`?

Comment: I just tried it.  Unfortunately, no.  Setting `self.deleteBarButtonItem.tintColor` did nothing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out the problem was that I was using a third party library, `SDCAlertView`, and I was setting

```
[[SDCAlertView appearance] setTintColor:globalTintColor];
```

For some reason, this caused all of my `UINavigationBar` objects to take on it's tintColor.

I fixed this by simply replacing the above code:

```
[[SDCAlertView appearance] setButtonTextColor:globalTintColor];
```

Comment: Note that `tintColor` and `UIAppearance` don't go well together (and is in fact not supported) in iOS 7. Your solution seems fine, though.

Comment: @ScottBerrevoets Thanks!  Perhaps that's why I was seeing unexpected behavior.  I was doing something that isn't supported anyway.