# IOS 8 Tab Bar Item Background Colour

Tags: ios, swift, ios8, uitabbar, uitabbaritem

I've been trying to find the solution to this for the last week, and I have had no luck after trying every possible solution I could find or think of. Every solution I found and have attempted has either not worked, or been outdated.

I have 5 `UITabBarItem`'s in a `UITabBar` placed within `UITabBarController`. I want to change the background color of the `UITabBarItem` when it is selected, and of course have it change back when the selected item changes.

I am using Swift, and iOS SDK 8.3 in Xcode 6.3.1. If you can only answer in Objective-C that is fine too, any answer will help! Thank you all in advance, I really appreciate it!

EDIT: Here is a visual example of what I would want it to do.

[Different Background Color](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CfIaO.jpg)

Answer (score 66):

In your tabBarController, you can set the default UITabBar tintColor, barTintColor, selectionIndicatorImage (cheating a bit here) and renderingMode of the images, see comments below:

```
    class MyTabBarController: UITabBarController, UINavigationControllerDelegate {
      ...
      override func viewDidLoad() {
        ...
        // Sets the default color of the icon of the selected UITabBarItem and Title
        UITabBar.appearance().tintColor = UIColor.redColor()

        // Sets the default color of the background of the UITabBar
        UITabBar.appearance().barTintColor = UIColor.blackColor()

        // Sets the background color of the selected UITabBarItem (using and plain colored UIImage with the width = 1/5 of the tabBar (if you have 5 items) and the height of the tabBar)
        UITabBar.appearance().selectionIndicatorImage = UIImage().makeImageWithColorAndSize(UIColor.blueColor(), size: CGSizeMake(tabBar.frame.width/5, tabBar.frame.height))

        // Uses the original colors for your images, so they aren't not rendered as grey automatically.
        for item in self.tabBar.items as! [UITabBarItem] {
          if let image = item.image {
            item.image = image.imageWithRenderingMode(.AlwaysOriginal)
          }
        }
      }
      ...
    }
```

And you will want to extend the UIImage class to make the plain colored image with the size you need:

```
extension UIImage {
  func makeImageWithColorAndSize(color: UIColor, size: CGSize) -> UIImage {
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(size, false, 0)
    color.setFill()
    UIRectFill(CGRectMake(0, 0, size.width, size.height))
    var image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
    return image
  }
}
```

Comment: Very nice answer, thanks. Someone should mark this as correct. In the UIImage extension you are passing a size but you are not using it. I think you meant to write UIRectFill(CGRectMake(0, 0, size.width, size.height)). If I replace this line your solution works perfectly.

Comment: This is the only answer that worked for me. Thanks. Only thing I'd change is "UITabBar.appearance().selectionIndicatorImage = UIImage()..." to "UITabBar.appearance().selectionIndicatorImage = UIImage().makeImageWithColorAndSize(UIColor.blueColor(), size: CGSizeMake(tabBar.frame.width/CGFloat(tabBar.items!.count), tabBar.frame.height))" just to make it a bit more plug and play.
Thanks again!

Comment: Should be selected as answer

Comment: My image isn't stretching out when I use the Iphone 6 simulator. I put the extension but it's still isn't working.

Comment: You will want to divide the the width and height by the screen scale factor in order to get the correct image size for different devices, e.g. `CGSize(width: size.width / UIScreen.main.scale, height: size.height / UIScreen.main.scale)`

Answer (score 20):

You can try this one. Add this in `AppDelegate.swift`.

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
        // Override point for customization after application launch.

        UITabBar.appearance().translucent = false
        UITabBar.appearance().barTintColor = UIColor(rgba: "#12296f")
        UITabBar.appearance().tintColor = UIColor.whiteColor()

        return true
    }
```

Don't forget to include this library. https://github.com/yeahdongcn/UIColor-Hex-Swift

Comment: But your icon will change the tab bar color based on selected item.

Answer (score 4):

Inspired by Gwendle, this is how I've solved it:

```
override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
    guard let tabBar = tabBarController?.tabBar else { return }
    tabBar.tintColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
    tabBar.selectionIndicatorImage = UIImage().makeImageWithColorAndSize(UIColor.redColor(), size: CGSizeMake(tabBar.frame.width/5, tabBar.frame.height))
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
}
```

And also used the extension:

```
extension UIImage {
    func makeImageWithColorAndSize(color: UIColor, size: CGSize) -> UIImage {
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(size)
        color.setFill()
        UIRectFill(CGRectMake(0, 0, size.width, size.height))
        let image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
        return image
}
```

Keep in mind that after you set the `selectionIndicationImage` it remains set for all your other tabs. Here's an example how to remove it, by setting it to nil in every other view controller in the remaining tabs:

```
override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
    tabBarController?.tabBar.tintColor = UIColor.redColor()
    tabBarController?.tabBar.selectionIndicatorImage = nil
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
}
```

Implemented using Swift 2.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this?

Select the tab bar icon image in your view controller in storyboard.

Look in the Identity and Type (far left) tab (it looks like a piece of paper) on the right panel of xcode.

Look for the global tint setting.

Comment: Yep, that's it.  Are you trying to change the global tint to just your tab bar, or for the entire program?   It doesn't work because it's probably overridden at a higher navigation level.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22313205/storyboard-global-tint-uitabbar-tint-changed-in-ios-7-1

Comment: Also make sure no lines of code are setting your tint color  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23818808/uibarbuttonitem-title-text-is-always-global-tint-color

Comment: Do you have a navigation controller as a part of your storyboard?

Comment: In storyboard, click the top part of your tab bar view controller.  Then open the attributes inspector.  Then play around with the simulated metrics to get what you want.

Comment: Yes I do, I have tried it but had no luck :( I updated the original post to include an example image of what i would want it to act like :) [Example](http://imgur.com/bEmUReK)

Comment: I see, I've never split the tab bar up like that.  I'm sorry I can't be of more help.

Answer (score 0):

You can call this function from each controller passing `self.tabBarController` and each color you want.

**Function :**

```
static func customTabBar(controller: UIViewController?, backgroundColor: String, unselectedColor: String, selectedColor: String) {
        if let tabBarController = controller as? UITabBarController {
            tabBarController.tabBar.barTintColor = UIColor(hex: backgroundColor)
            tabBarController.tabBar.tintColor = UIColor(hex: selectedColor)
            tabBarController.tabBar.isTranslucent = false
            tabBarController.tabBar.selectedItem?.setTitleTextAttributes([NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor:UIColor(hex: selectedColor)], for: UIControl.State.selected)
            if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
                tabBarController.tabBar.unselectedItemTintColor = UIColor(hex: unselectedColor)
            } else {
                // Fallback on earlier versions
            }
        }
    }
```