# Custom tab bar background color. How to change color of tab bar background?

Tags: ios, iphone, swift

i want to change the color of tab bar background and i want to put my own color with color code, how to do that? I have the color code from sketch and dont know how to code that in swift.

Comment: try navigationController?.toolbar.barTintColor = UIColor.green // any colour

Comment: do i need to create a subclass for tab bar ? or can i put his code in appdelegate?

Comment: in viewDidLoad.....

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30041127/ios-8-tab-bar-item-background-colour

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the viewController class for your tab bar put one of the following sections of code into your view did load depending on what values you have.

```
self.tabBar.barTintColor = UIColor.init(red: <#T##CGFloat#>, green: <#T##CGFloat#>, blue: <#T##CGFloat#>, alpha: <#T##CGFloat#>)
```

or

```
self.tabBar.barTintColor = UIColor.init(hue: <#T##CGFloat#>, saturation: <#T##CGFloat#>, brightness: <#T##CGFloat#>, alpha: <#T##CGFloat#>)
```

Comment: When i add this code in the CustomTabBar class, so i get error like "UIColor" has no member "UIColor"

Comment: Sorry about that I have miss typed the top one and put UIColor twice should just be UIColor.init(), will edit my answer

Answer (score 1):

Try this code:

```
navigationController?.toolbar.barTintColor = UIColor.green // You can set to any colour.
```

Answer (score 0):

You can specify in `AppDelegate.swift` how the appearance of your `UITabBar` will be:

```
UITabBar.appearance().barTintColor = .white
```

If you would like a method for custom colors using hex code, you can add an extension to `UIColor` like this:

```
extension UIColor {
    convenience init (for hex: Int) {
        let red: Int =        (hex >> 16) & 0xff
        let green: Int =      (hex >> 8)  & 0xff
        let blue: Int =       hex         & 0xff

        assert(
            (red >= 0 && red <= 255) &&
            (green >= 0 && green <= 255) &&
            (blue >= 0 && blue <= 255),
            "bad hex for UIColor"
        )

        self.init (red: CGFloat(red) / 255.0, green: CGFloat (green) / 255.0, blue: CGFloat (blue) / 255.0, alpha: 1.0)
    }

    // Create your own custom color from hex code
    public class var customColor: UIColor {
        return UIColor (for: 0x0067DF)
    }
}
```

Then you can change your `UITabBar` background color to your own custom one:

```
UITabBar.appearance().barTintColor = .customColor
```