# How to change the background color of tab bar programatically?

Tags: ios, swift, uitabbar

My goal is simple, change the default background color of tab bar to my own color.

For example, the default looks like this

[image]

I created my own subclass of UITabBarController, so that I don't need to change the color on every UIViewController

```
import UIKit

class MyTabController: UITabBarController {

    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
        self.tabBar.backgroundColor = .black
    }
}
```

The result is different from what I expected.

[image]

I thought that maybe it's the color, then I changed to a custom UIColor and the color looks exactly the same.

I tried changing the bar tint color as well, but its change the color of the icon when active, not the background

```
self.tabBar.tintColor = UIColor(red:1.00, green:0.23, blue:0.19, alpha:1.0)
```

The result will be

[image]

What did I do wrong?

Comment: use [UITabBar appearance] Here is nice answer for swift
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30041127/ios-8-tab-bar-item-background-colour

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `self.tabBar.barTintColor` or have a look at [UIBarStyle](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uibarstyle) and `self.tabBar.barStyle` and see if that works.

Comment: barTintColor just change the color of the icon not the background

Comment: Now just to be sure, you tried barTintColor and not tintColor?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with my app but I wanted to set up a gradient image in tabbar background and I came up with following:
in *applicationDidFinishLaunching* method I created a function to draw a gradient and used an instance of my UITabBarController to set up a correct gradient frame depending on the width of the device.

```
- (UIImage *)drawGradientInView:(UITabBarController *) tabBarVC {
    CAGradientLayer *gradient = [CAGradientLayer layer];
gradient.frame = CGRectMake(CGRectGetMinX(tabBarVC.tabBar.frame), CGRectGetMinY(tabBarVC.tabBar.frame), CGRectGetWidth(tabBarVC.view.frame), CGRectGetHeight(tabBarVC.tabBar.frame));

    //set up your gradient
    //......

    UIImage *gradientImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    return gradientImage;
}
```

get the instance of UITabBarController

```
UITabBarController *tabVC = (UITabBarController *)[UIApplication sharedApplication].windows.firstObject.rootViewController;
```

set your gradient

```
[UITabBar appearance].backgroundImage = [self drawGradientInView:tabVC];
```

I'm not sure if that's a correct approach but it did work for me.